# select randomly from a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to randomly select from "outcome" variable. " outcome" variable has 3 sub category of "Major_effect","Minor_Effect","Moderate Effect". I need to select 2288 of each. in other word:
2288 minor effects, 2288 major effects and 2288 moderate effect"
. The codes i wrote is as below:but it didn't work.

```
selectedlist=["Major_effect","Minor_Effect","Moderate Effect"]
idx = []
for classname in selectedlist:
    randomchoice = random.choices((df8[df8["outcome"] == classname]), k=2288).index.tolist()
    idx.extend(selectedlist)
df8
```

KeyError: 0

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Use `df8[...].sample(n=2288)`